# text file contains lines of bizarre characters - want to fix

Tags: linux, encoding, character, controls

I'm an inexperienced programmer grappling with a new problem in a large text file which contains data I am trying to process.  Here's a screen capture of what I'm looking at (using 'less' - I am on a linux server):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VAqfRxlxGpaW53THBNeGh5N2c/view?usp=sharing

Bioinformaticians will recognize this file as a "fastq" file containing DNA sequence data.  The top half of the screenshot contains data in its expected format (which I admit contains some "bizarre" characters, but that is not the issue).  However, the bottom half (with many characters shaded in white) is completely messed up.  If I were to scroll down the file, it eventually returns to normal text after about 500 lines. I want to fix it because it is breaking downstream operations I am trying to perform (which complain about precisely this position in the file).

Is there a way to grep for and remove the shaded lines? Or can I fix this problem by somehow changing the encoding on the offending lines?

Thanks

Comment: put the picture output in text form in your question..it will be easier to test and remove to get your expected output

Comment: @Xorg - I don't think this will work.  The issue (I think) is that the shaded characters are not literals but terminal representations of control characters and hex code (I believe this is also why your regex has no effect).  When I copy and paste to SO, these characters just get converted to their literal representation, so won't be useful for testing.  I need some way to recognize these special characters and get rid of them.  I've had some success today with awk, which I will post once I get it working as I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, you can use

```
strings file > file2
```

Oh well, try it another way.

Determine the linelength of the correct lines (I think the first two lines are different).

```
head -1 file | wc -c
head -2 file | tail -1 | wc -c
```

Hmm, wc also counts the line-ending, substract 1 from both lengths.

Than try to read the file 1 line a time. Use a case-statement so you do not have to write a lot of else-if constructions for comparing the length to the expected length. In the code I will accept the lengths 20, 100 and 330
Redirect everything to another file outside the loop (inside will overwrite each line).

```
cat file | while read -r line; do
   case ${#line} in
      20|100|330) echo $line ;;
   esac
done > file2
```

A total different approach would be filtering the wrong lines with sed, awk or grep but that would require knowledge what characters you will and won't accept.
Yes, when you are a lucky (wo-)man, all ugly lines will have a character in common like '<' or maybe an '@'. In that case you can use egrep:

```
egrep -v "<|@" file > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

BASED ON **INSPECTION** OF THE **SNAP**

```
sed -r 's/<[[:alnum:]]{2}>//g;s/\^.//g;s/ESC\^*C*//g' file
```

to make the actual changes in the file and make a backup file with a .bak extension do

```
  sed -r -i.bak 's/<[[:alnum:]]{2}>//g;s/\^.//g;s/ESC\^*C*//g' file
```

Comment: Please see my reply to your comment in the original post.  Unfortunately this regex does not alter my file.

Comment: I see...I was of the opinion that these data with their terminal representations were in the "large text file" as mentioned...my bad